# PDF not rendering using ng2-pdfjs-viewer dependency

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer

I am using Angular-15, I wanted to show PDF file from my spring-boot server and render on my HTML page of NG App. after trying for 1 week with different approaches, I finally personally believe that this plug-in does have some best potential and maintainable, but it is somehow messed up in integration. looking for some real great help from champions of angular.

so, exploring about this use case
my Backend API
Controller

```
@GetMapping("/file/v3/{fileNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findFileV3(@PathVariable("fileNumber") String fileNumber) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(filePreviewService.getFileV3(fileNumber), null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and its corresponding service

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFileV3(String fileNumber) {
        byte[] pdfBytes = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = null;
        try {
            FileBO file = fileService.findByFileNumber(fileNumber);
            if (file != null) {
                String filePath = file .getBillRef();
                Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
                pdfBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

                headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(pdfBytes);
    }
```

and now Angular part component.ts file

```
  pdfUrl: any;
  pdfSrc: any;

  getPdf(): void {
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/file/v3/INVSY22TCS202307';

    const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken });
    let header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken });
    this.http.get(apiUrl, { headers:header, responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).subscribe(
      (response: ArrayBuffer) => {
        const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => {
          this.pdfSrc = fileReader.result as string;
          console.log("[PDF_SRC]: "+this.pdfSrc);

          const action = "PDF Received";
          this.modalData = { action: action, data: null };
          this.modalRef = this.modal.open(this.pdfPreviewer, { size: 'lg' });
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }
```

HTML code

```
<ng-template #pdfPreviewer let-close="close">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Preview Mode</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>PDF Preview</label>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
          <!-- <ng2-pdfjs-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer> -->
          <ng2-pdfjs-viewer [pdfSrc]="pdfSrc"></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

from my backend server I do receive PDF byte content attaching screen shot for this.
[image]

I am trying out as documentation https://github.com/intbot/ng2-pdfjs-viewer, but seems like it is somewhere problem and I am not getting any clues for that.